# Download the source file did not save the update

Tags: overleaf

I use Overleaf online and I am trying to download the source of my project but I have problem here, When I download just the pdf file I can see my update on the file but when download it as source the update on the text did not save on the pdf and the source is like the copy that created before the update. Why?

Comment: I know that this post will be deleted after my answer here... But I will answer. The pdf inside the source code should not be there at all. The zip contains that pdf just as an extra file that should be deleted from the code or should not be there while uploading. The pdf and the source are completely separate files, This is all. Happy TeXing!\

Comment: Can I delete the pdf file in the source? and when compiling my updated pdf is it save in the source?

Comment: the result pdf should not show in your overleaf project files in the left sidebar,if you uploaded it, delete it

Comment: No pdf is saved in the source... download the pdf separately. This is all. Source is only source... pdf is the output of the source. You need no pdf's in the source as far as they are not contained (as figures or as pdfs) in the input you are giving.

Comment: But I need my new pdf be in the source because I need to send my source with new pdf. Can I ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, if I delete it, the new one will create in the overleaf project files in the left sidebar ?

Comment: Delete it... Compile... Download the source AND the pdf... Unzip... place in the folder the pdf you downloaded... Zip... And send.

Comment: Yes, I did that, THANKS :)

Comment: source files are source files: the generated files never appear there. The pdf you uploaded is unchanged and unrelated to the pdf generated by latex.